# Testing TIFF data gives ?conflicting? bit depths in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, binary, tiff

I'm trying to write a function in Matlab that reads in TIFF images from various cameras and restores them to their correct data values for analysis. These cameras are from a variety of brands, and, so far, store either 12 or 14 bit data into 16 bit output. I've been reading them in using imread, and I was told that dividing by either 16 or 4 would convert the data back to it's original form. Unfortunately, that was when the function was only intended for one brand of camera specifically, which nicely scales data to 16 bit at time of capture so that such a transformation would work.

Since I'd like to keep the whole image property detection thing as automated as possible, I've done some digging in the data for a couple different cameras, and I'm running into an issue that I must be completely clueless about. I've determined (so far) that the pictures will always be stored in one of two ways: such that the previous method will work (they multiply the original data out to fill the 16 bits), or they just stuff the data in directly and append zeroes to the front or back for any vacant bits. I decided to see if I could detect which was which and have been using the following two methods. The images I test should easily have values that fill up the full range from zero to saturation (though sometimes not quite), and are fairly large resolution, so in theory these methods should work:

I start by reading in the image data:

```
Mframe = imread('signal.tif');
```

This method attempts to detect the number of bits that ever get used:

```
bits = 0;
for i = 1:16
  Bframe = bitget(Mframe,i);
  bits = bits + max(max(Bframe));
end
```

And this method attempts to find if there has been a scaling operation done:

```
Mframe = imread('signal.tif');
Dframe = diff(Mframe);
mindiff = min(min(nonzeros(Dframe)));
```

As a 3rd check I always look at the maximum value of my input image:

```
maxval = max(max(Mframe));
```

Please check my understanding here:

1. The value of maxval should be at 65532 in the case of a 16 bit image containing any saturation.
2. If the 12 or 14 bit data has been scaled to 16 bit, it should return maxval of 65532, a mindiff of 16 or 4 respectively, and bits as 16.
3. If the 12 or 14 bit data was stored directly with leading/trailing zeros, it can't return a maxval of 65532, mindiff should not return 16 or 4 (though it IS remotely possible), and bits should show as 12 or 14 respectively.
4. If an image is actually not reaching saturation, it can't return a maxval of 65532, mindiff should still act as described for the two cases above, and bits could possibly return as one lower than it otherwise would.

Am I correct in the above? If not please show me what I'm not understanding (I'm definitely not a computer scientist), because I seem to be getting data that conflicts with this.

Only one case appears to work just like I expect. I know the data to be 12 bit, and my testing shows maxval near 65532, mindiff of 16, and bits as 15. I can conclude that this image is not saturated and is a 12 bit scaled to 16 bit.

Another case for a different brand I know to have 12 bit output, and testing an image that I know isn't quite saturated gives me maxval of 61056, mindiff of 16, and bits as 12. ???

Yet another case, for yet again another brand, is known to have 14 bit output, and when I test an image I know to be saturated it gives me maxval of 65532, mindiff of 4, and bits as 15. ???

So very confused.

Comment: Looks like I made an amateur error in my assumptions! My bitget operation will not return results as I originally expected, since the top bit represents 2^15, which will most likely be used, so in any picture I should instead expect all 16 bits to be used at some point if there is a scaling operation done.

So basically, while this kind of changes the issues I'm having, it certainly doesn't solve them at all.

Comment: Would it be easier to test if all *lowest* bits are all zero? "Multiplying by 16" is actually the same as "stuffing the lowest bits with zeroes". If you find all pixels have a random value in bit #3 and bits 0..2 are always zero, that would be a signal.

Comment: Well, the bitget operation tests for all of the bits, and I can see from that which ones are zeros if I want by storing the results in the loop in an array.

Comment: So basically, I'm kind of new to understanding how the bits all kind of work, for which I apologize. I did some further tests and found that 65532 is the max for a stuffed 14 bit, and 65520 is the max for a stuffed 12 bit. These could also be considered "scaled" if the bottom zeros are the ones that are appended, and hence should return a minimum difference that corresponds with the correct pixel depth as well, I think.

I've discovered for a particular brand that the output has some "corrections" throwing off the bitget operation. I guess I just needed a sounding board, but thanks!

Comment: Looks like I need a little more help if anyone has ideas. I can't figure out why this would be, but the mindiff is returning as 16 on a set of data that apparently uses all 16 bits at some point according to bitget. That's not possible, right?? If the lowest bits were being used, wouldn't I find differences of 1, 2, 4, and 8? I even double-checked using `rem(Dframe,16)` and it didn't return anything but zeros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a lot of digging I finally figured it all out. I wrote some code to help me understand the differences between the different files and discovered that a couple of the cameras had "signatures" of sorts in them. I'm contacting the manufacturers for more information, but one in particular appears to be a timestamp that always occurs in the first 2 pixels.

Anyhow, I wrote the following code to fix the two issues I found and now everything is working peachy:

```
Mframe = imread('signal.tiff');

minval = min(min(Mframe));
mindiff = min(min(nonzeros(diff(Mframe))));
fixbit = log2(double(mindiff));

if rem(fixbit,2)    % Correct Brand A Issues

    fixbit = fixbit + 1;
    Bframe = bitget(Mframe,fixbit);
    [x,y] = find(Bframe==1);

    for i=1:length(x)
        Mframe(x(i),y(i)) = Mframe(x(i),y(i)) + mindiff;
    end

end

for i=1:4   % Correct Brand B Timestamp

    Bframe = bitget(Mframe,i);

    if any(any(Bframe))
        Mframe(1,1) = minval; Mframe(1,2) = minval;
    end

end

for i = 1:16    % Get actual bit depth
    Bframe = bitget(Mframe,i);
    bits = bits + max(max(Bframe));
end
```

As for the Brand A issues, that camera appears to have bad data in just a few pixels of every frame (not the same every time) where a value appears in a pixel that is a one bit lower difference than should be possible from the pixel below it. For example, in a 12 bit picture the minimum difference should be 16 and a 14 bit picture should have a minimum difference of 4, but they have values that are 8 and 2 lower than the pixel below them. Don't know why that's happening, but it was fairly simple to gloss over.